# show different images after click on different li (as a second menu)

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

This is my html as a second menu in a page.

```
<ul class="nav-tabs text-center" role="tablist">
         <li class="active"><a href="#breakfast" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lunch</a></li>
         <li class="diner"><a href="#lunch" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Diner</a></li>
         <li class="pannenkoek"><a href="#dinner" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pannenkoek</a></li>
         <li class="borrel"><a href="#dessert" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Borrel</a></li>

</ul>
```

Now when i want to click on a li there has to show an image. When you click on the second link there has to show another image. The problem now is when i click on a link, it doesn't matter which one, it shows al the images on the page of all the divs.

```
 <div class="active"><img src="images/themenu/lunchkaart-november.jpg"    alt="lunchkaart" /> </div>


<div class="diner"><img src="images/themenu/dinerkaart-januari.jpg" alt="dinerkaart" /> </div>
```

How te create when click on li lunch, it show image lunch.
When click on li diner, it show image diner.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: can u write and show the whole code here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zghc56xg/

Comment: Where are the images supposed to be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zghc56xg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery for that. Use this or maybe add class active for clicked element div. Also active class most be display:block or display:inline-block;

```
<ul class="nav-tabs text-center" role="tablist">
         <li class="lunch"><a href="#breakfast" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lunch</a></li>
         <li class="diner"><a href="#lunch" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Diner</a></li>
         <li class="pannenkoek"><a href="#dinner" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pannenkoek</a></li>
         <li class="borrel"><a href="#dessert" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Borrel</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="content">

<div class="lunch" style="display:none"><img src="images/themenu/lunchkaart-november.jpg"    alt="lunchkaart" /> </div>


<div class="diner" style="display:none"><img src="images/themenu/dinerkaart-januari.jpg" alt="dinerkaart" /> </div>

</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.nav-tabs li').click(function(){
        var elementClass = jQuery(this).attr("class").toString();
        console.log(elementClass);
        jQuery('.content div').hide();
            jQuery('.'+elementClass,'.content').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e79g4p1p/14/